# Can't find the cause of my app crashing

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I am working on a UIPickerController.  I have everything working but when I tap the back button to go to my previous view the app is crashing.

I am thinking it could be catching a memory leak.

Here is my code.  If anyone sees something I have missed or may have a clue on what cause this please inform me.  Nothing displays in the Debugger.

```
@synthesize colorTextField, pickerView, pickerToolbar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [colorTextField release];
    [pickerView release];
    [pickerToolbar release];
    [super dealloc];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    colorsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Red"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Orange"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Yellow"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Green"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Blue"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Indigo"];
    [colorsArray addObject:@"Violet"];
}

- (void)setColor
{    
     actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];   

     [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

     CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);  
     pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];  
     pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;  
     pickerView.dataSource = self;  
     pickerView.delegate = self;  

     [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
     [pickerView release];

     pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, actionSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [pickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];

     [pickerToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton] animated:NO];
     [doneButton release];

     [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];
     [pickerToolbar release];

     [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

     [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];  
}

- (void)pickerDoneClicked
{    
   [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self setColor];
    return NO;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

     return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
     return [colorsArray count];
 }

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [colorsArray objectAtIndex:row];
 }

 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [colorsArray objectAtIndex:row], row);
    [colorTextField setText:(NSString *)[colorsArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setColorTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 @end
```

Comment: It helps you and other users if you are slightly more selective in the code you are posting. For example, the initWithNibName:bundle: and didReceiveMemoryWarning code here are just template code. No need to post them. You could probably also be confident that, say, the shouldAutoroateToInterfaceOrientation: method didn't need to be included given the nature of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your release some of your items mor ethan once
EG:

in the dealloc you have two 
[pickerView release];
[pickerToolbar release];

that are release already 
eg:
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerView release];

so it has nothing to release me thinks, so remove the duplicate releases??

Answer (score 2):

You're double-releasing `pickerView` and `pickerToolbar`, once in `setColor` and again in `dealloc`.

A good pattern when releasing views held in ivars is to set the ivar to nil after releasing the view, this will prevent double-releases.

Comment: Thanks so much guys!  I guess this just slipped my sight.  Could anyone help explain to me how to set up multiple UIPicker's?  Would it be to just use if statements of some sort?

Comment: @LukeIrvin: What, multiple pickers with the same delegate? Yes, just do if statements in the delegate methods to test `thePickerView` to determine which picker is being used. If you need more help, feel free to post a new question.